# Is the dual space of a separable normed space also separable?

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

If $X$ is a real normed space such that $X^*$ (the dual) is separable then $X$ is also separable. Is the converse true, *i.e.*, if $X$ is separable then is its dual space $X^*$ necessarily separable?

Answer (score 8):

No. For example, $L^1([0,1])$ is separable but its dual is not.

Answer (score 5):

Of course, $\ell_1$ is the paradigm example of a separable space with non-separable dual ($\ell_1^*\cong \ell_\infty$). It has been an open problem for many years whether containment of an isomorphic copy of $\ell_1$ is the only obstacle for separability of the dual space.

There is an unexpected counter-example to this statement by R. C. James, the so-called James tree space $JT$. Every closed subspace of $JT$ contains a copy of $\ell_2$ (so $\ell_1$ does not embed into $JT$), yet the dual of $JT$ is non-separable. You will find a nice exposition of this space in

> Helga Fetter and Berta Gamboa de Buen, *The James forest*, Cambridge University Press, Cambridge, 1997.